# Way to separate out individual events

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a large dataset with observations every 1/2 second. It represents a series of milkings in a robot. So a cow enters the robot and gets milked while different things are measured. Then the cow leaves and for a while there is no cow until another cow enters. I wrote code for an oversimplified sample of my data.

**Sample Data**

```
set.seed(66)
ID <- rep(c(84,-999,88,-999),c(5,3,7,5))
TimeStamp <- rep(c("09:31:12",NA,"09:45:31",NA),c(5,3,7,5))
VAR1 <- sample(x = 800:3000, 20)
mydf <- data.frame(ID=ID, TimeStamp=TimeStamp, VAR1 = VAR1)
eventIDs <- as.numeric(factor(mydf[, "TimeStamp"], exclude = NULL))
mydf[, "eventIDs"] <- eventIDs
mydf
#     ID TimeStamp VAR1 eventIDs
#1    84  09:31:12 2978        1
#2    84  09:31:12 2625        1
#3    84  09:31:12 2088        1
#4    84  09:31:12 1716        1
#5    84  09:31:12 2254        1
#6  -999      <NA> 1632        3
#7  -999      <NA> 1731        3
#8  -999      <NA> 2648        3
#9    88  09:45:31 1625        2
#10   88  09:45:31 2798        2
#11   88  09:45:31 1366        2
#12   88  09:45:31 1245        2
#13   88  09:45:31 1291        2
#14   88  09:45:31 2801        2
#15   88  09:45:31 2746        2
#16 -999      <NA> 1411        3
#17 -999      <NA> 1738        3
#18 -999      <NA> 1398        3
#19 -999      <NA> 1918        3
#20 -999      <NA> 1575        3
```

The `ID` variable in the data represents the cow/no-cow event. The `-999` was decided on when `ID == NA`. The `TimeStamp` represents the start of milking. This variable is used to identify the `eventIDs` variable. This is important because over the course of the day cows can be milked multiple times. That's why it was created in order to separate out each milking event for each cow. `VAR1` represents whatever variable that is being investigated.

**Desired Output**

I need the mean of `VAR1` for each milking and each non-milking. Currently, this is the output I have:

```
(res1 <- aggregate(mydf[,"VAR1"],
                   by = list(ID = mydf[,"ID"], eventIDs = mydf[,"eventIDs"]),
                   FUN = mean))
#    ID eventIDs        x
#1   84        1 2332.200
#2   88        2 1981.714
#3 -999        3 1756.375
```

This is obvious results because there is no indicator variable that separates out each successive 'non-milking' event. In fact I would like this:

```
meanVAR1 <- c((2978+2625+2088+1716+2254)/5,
              (1632+1731+2648)/3,
              (1625+2798+1366+1245+1291+2801+2746)/7,
              (1411+1738+1398+1918+1575)/5) 
eventIDs <- c(1,3,2,3) 
(res2 <- data.frame(ID = ID1, meanVAR1 = meanVAR1, eventIDs = eventIDs))
#    ID meanVAR1 eventIDs
#1   84 2332.200        1
#2 -999 2003.667        3
#3   88 1981.714        2
#4 -999 1608.000        3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is sorted as in your example chronologically. Using `rle`it is quite easy to create a proxy ID that is unique for each event:

```
mydf$ID2 = rep(1:length(rle(mydf$ID)$lengths),times=rle(mydf$ID)$lengths)
```

Then in conjunction with `aggregate` or as in my example `data.table` this new ID will help us get the desired result:

```
setDT(mydf)[,list(meanVar1=mean(VAR1)),by=c("ID","ID2","eventIDs")]
   #       ID ID2 eventIDs meanVar1
   # 1:   84 1   1        1 2332.200
   # 2: -999 2   2        3 2003.667
   # 3:   88 3   3        2 1981.714
   # 4: -999 4   4        3 1608.000
```

Comment: works nicely! i wish i could mark two answers. --Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Using [devel version of data.table v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), which implements a new function `rleid()` to make use of in these situations:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
ans = setDT(mydf)[, .(meanVAR1 = mean(VAR1)), by=.(ID, eventIDs, rleid(ID))]    
#      ID eventIDs rleid meanVAR1
# 1:   84        1     1 2332.200
# 2: -999        3     2 2003.667
# 3:   88        2     3 1981.714
# 4: -999        3     4 1608.000
```

If you don't want the `rleid` column, you can remove it by doing:

```
ans[, rleid := NULL]
```

Have a look at the [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) to learn more.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to install Rtools on my university computer. But I am working on it because I really need latest data.table version for other pieces of code too. I will test it at home. But I am sure it works! --Cheers